# RSpec - Password can't be blank error after installing Devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise

I test User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :password, :presence => true

  has_many :ads,             dependent: :destroy
  has_many :docs,            through: :ads, source: :content, source_type: "Doc"
  has_many :pets,            through: :ads, source: :content, source_type: "Pet"
  has_many :license_plates,  through: :ads, source: :content, source_type:                 "LicensePlate"
end
```

users schema is following:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  end
```

Factory is:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    phone { Faker::PhoneNumber.phone_number }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    encrypted_password { Faker::Internet.password }
    #reset_password_token
  end
end
```

RSpec code is:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  it "has a valid factory" do

    expect(FactoryGirl.build(:user)).to be_valid

  end

  it { is_expected.to have_many(:ads).dependent(:destroy) }
  it { is_expected.to have_many(:docs).through(:ads) }
  it { is_expected.to have_many(:pets).through(:ads) }
  it { is_expected.to have_many(:license_plates).through(:ads) }

end
```

Running rspec I have "Password can't be blank" error [image]

What can cause "Password can't be blank" error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in your factory, change `encrypted_password` to `password`

Comment: Cool! Tests passed! Thanks a million indeed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion of @jvnil is right. As you can see in the Devise code https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb

```
  # Verifies whether an password (ie from sign in) is the user password.
  def valid_password?(password)
    return false if encrypted_password.blank?
    bcrypt   = ::BCrypt::Password.new(encrypted_password)
    password = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("#{password}#{self.class.pepper}", bcrypt.salt)
    Devise.secure_compare(password, encrypted_password)
  end
```

#

```
# Generates password encryption based on the given value.
      def password=(new_password)
        @password = new_password
        self.encrypted_password = password_digest(@password) if @password.present?
      end
```

And validates that at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/strategies/database_authenticatable.rb

```
resource  = valid_password? && mapping.to.find_for_database_authentication(authentication_hash)
```